# Mono for Android - Get executable name

Tags: android, mono

In Mono for Android i'm tryin to extract (at runtime) the application name, with path, but i can't find anything working (there are hours I'm serching over internet and trying, but nothing seem to work).
I need the name to obtain FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(fn);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the app version at runtime , you can try using the following code.

```
var appVersion = PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(PackageName, 0).VersionCode;
```

And here is some code to get the package name programmatically

```
var actMngr = (ActivityManager)GetSystemService (Context.ActivityService);
var runningPkg = actMngr.GetRunningTasks(1)[0].TopActivity.PackageName;

PackageManager pm = this.PackageManager;
ApplicationInfo ai = pm.GetApplicationInfo(runningPkg, 0);
```

Remember, that it requires the GET_TASKS permission to be set in your manifest...

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```